# Python Pandas data_range

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm trying to get every month between a given date range using data_range function in pandas. However, if I set the end the date to be the last date of a month, it's returning an extra month for me. How can I fix this?

```
[In]: pd.date_range(*(pd.to_datetime(['01/01/2020', '03/30/2020']) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()), freq='M')
```

This returns no problem:

```
[Out]: DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-31', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

However if I change the end date to be '03/31/2020', it returns:

```
[Out]: DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-31', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-31', '2020-04-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

What I'm looking for is to make both '01/01/2020' to '03/30/2020' and '01/01/2020' to '03/31/2020' return the same output, which is ['2020-01-31', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-31'].

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)` instead, that will solve your problem:

```
pd.date_range(*(pd.to_datetime(['01/01/2020', '03/31/2020']) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)), freq='M')

DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-31', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

The cleaner solution is to use resample in my opinion:

```
rng = pd.date_range(*(pd.to_datetime(['01/01/2020', '03/31/2020'])), freq='M')
rng.to_series().resample('M').last()

2020-01-31   2020-01-31
2020-02-29   2020-02-29
2020-03-31   2020-03-31
Freq: M, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```